# $this->getImageMedia(); -> \catalog\product\view\media.phtml?

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, layout, template

I've isolated a bit of Magento code which accesses a template file `catalog\product\view\media.phtml`:

```
<?php echo $this->getImagesMedia(); ?>
```

How is this different than the below example which does the same thing:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
```

The second example makes sense to me because it's defined in the layout.xml.. The first example is easier to implement on a catalog page where you have multiple objects but where is the `$this->getImagesMedia()` defined or setup?

How would I create a `$this->getImagesMediaMobile()`.. that's my goal.. to have a 2nd way to display images on mobile devices.

Comment: you can refer the iphone theme media.phtml file

Comment: @KeyulShah That doesn't resolve the question though as requires running the iPhone theme for mobiles (as opposed to a global responsive theme with conditional loading as required).

Comment: @zigojacko .. you're right on with what im trying to do.. could you please extrapolate a little bit more about this (if you can) as an answer??

Comment: Where did you find `<?php echo $this->getImagesMedia(); ?>` ? I wasn't able to find it anywhere.

Comment: Marius, I can look into this for you.. but could it be EE specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I cannot find the code `getImagesMedia` anywhere and in the media.phtml the following is used

```
$this->getGalleryImages()
```

But even though I am not sure what you are talking about I can give you a general answer as to the difference between the following calls.

**$this->getSomething() or $this->getData('something')**

These are calls to get values directly from the block object, there will either be a function that matches in the block or at some point there will be a call to `setSomething`

**$this->getChildHtml('something') or $this->getChild('something')**

Now these two will either return the html or the block itself from a child block defined via the layout xml as follows.

```
<block name="your_parent_block">
    <block type="some/type" name="something" />
</block>
```

Comment: Your more generalized answer is more helpful. Thank you for breaking this down.

Answer (score 0):

Function and Method Cross Reference

getgalleryimages()

Defined at:
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Media.php -> line 43

Referenced 6 times:

- /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml -> line 67
- /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml -> line 71
- /app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml -> line 67
- /app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml -> line 71
- /app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml -> line 46
- /app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml -> line 47